# MxGraph: Can't Search and Focus on cells

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I've been trying to make a simple input element to search for id's and focus on specific vertexes, as shown below:

[Screen before Searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7MJm.png)

And the code seems to be working with this simple method:

```
function searchForNode() {
    const id = document.getElementById("input-search-id").value;
    const { vertex } = findById(id);

    const point = new mxPoint(-(vertex.geometry.x), -(vertex.geometry.y));
    graph.view.translate = point;
}
```

The problem starts after the first search, where my top left screen focuses on the desired vertex but from there on I'm enabled to scroll up or left.

[Screen after Searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCXvy.png)

Also, if I scroll before searching for anything, it seems that my graph.view.translate doesn't update to my current position, so, when I search for a vertex it focuses on a different location instead of the expected vertex.

Is there any method from MxGraph Library that I'm missing? I've tried graph.getView().setTranslate(translate) and graph.panGraph(translate) but the behaviour is the same.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a solution for this problem but not in the most convenient way.

For what I understood, the native scrollbars and the mxGraph panning are different approaches to the display movement, when you scroll you aren't necessarily updating your mxGraph position but when you pan with the mxGraph library you are dragging all the cells along the screen, instead of "scrolling" to them.

I disabled the mxGraph panning option and simply used the javascript native method scrollTo, as show below, I hope it helps.

```
function searchForNode() {
  const inputValue = document.getElementById("input-search-id").value;
  const { vertex } = flowMap.findNodeByIdOrName(inputValue);
  if( !vertex ) return null;
  
  window.scrollTo({
    top: vertex.geometry.y - MARGIN_TO_CENTER,
    left: vertex.geometry.x - MARGIN_TO_CENTER,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });
}
```

*The flowMap.findNodeByIdOrName on the last image and the findById(id) on the question post are my own methods to search on my array of vertexes.

Comment: DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @cursorrux Sure thing. I've already made the suggested changes

Answer (score 0):

You may use [scrollCellToVisible](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/view/mxGraph-js.html#mxGraph.scrollCellToVisible)

Comment: Hello! Thank you for your answer. Can you please provide more information on how this helps OP's problem? Answers should preferably be self contained, meaning all necessary information to understand the answer should be written in the answer and not in external links because links can break over time. (Feel free to quote a source and link to it, but please put the important information here)